# Set font for ListView, Android

Tags: java, android, listview, fonts

I spent all day searching for an answer, found a lot, but all of them are not what I need.
So, I have a pretty simple menu with ListView and a file for items with TextView. I want to set Segoe-Print font for items in my menu, I know, that I need adapter, but I can't do it. Help!!!

menu.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/menu_top"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@drawable/menu_top">
       </LinearLayout>

<ListView 
          android:id="@+id/ListView_Menu"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="@drawable/fon_android"
          android:divider="@drawable/menu_line"
          android:textStyle="bold" >
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

menu_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/menu_prop"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:textSize="19px"
android:text="test string"
android:layout_gravity="left"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:shadowRadius="5"
android:textColor="@color/menu_color"
android:shadowDy="3"
android:shadowDx="3" />
```

A part of Main_Menu.java:

```
public class Main_menu extends Activity {
    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);
        ListView menuList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView_Menu);
        String[] items = { 
                getResources().getString(R.string.system),
                getResources().getString(R.string.convert),
                getResources().getString(R.string.forks),
                getResources().getString(R.string.margin)};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.menu_item, items);
    menuList.setAdapter(adapt);
}
```

CustomAdapter.java:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

       public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, String[] objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

    public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
              View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
              TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.menu_prop);
              Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "segoe_print.ttf"); 
              textView.setTypeface(font);
            return textView;
       }

    private AssetManager getAssets() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
  }
```

The font doesn't change...

Answer (score 1):

```
view.txtViewTitle.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(parent
                .getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/DroidSerif.ttf"));
```

Answer (score 0):

here is code for custom adapter:

```
private class CostumiseAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<item>{

public CostumiseAdapter(ArrayList<item> items) {
 super(getActivity(), 0, items);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
 if(convertView == null){
convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.scroll_fragment, null);
}

Item item = getItem(position);

TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
text.setText(item.mString);

RadioButton b1 = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radio_b1);
b1.setChecked(item.mB1);

RadioButton b2 = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radio_b2);
b2.setChecked(item.mB2);

CheckBox cB = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.check_box);
cB.setChecked(item.mB2);

return convertView;
}
}
```

I've take it from http://androide-examples.blogspot.com/2013/11/android-scroll-list.html see for the full example.

In this example are some semantik mistakes. So you have to fix some items to Items (capitalise)...

Comment: @user2877972 is this helpful for you?

Comment: It looks as if I go around the closed door that I just have to pull over, but do not push as I try. Today I will read the documentation carefully - the adapter mechanism is not yet understood.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom adapter for setting custom font. Here is the minimal code :

```
  public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
   //Contructor here

       public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
              View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
              TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
             // Here you set the typeface as you do for the TextView 
              textView.setTypeFace(....);
       }
  }
```

That should provide you the custom font for your Listview.

Comment: Something wrong... Please, look at the first post - I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a desition! 
Well, first of all I create another class for Adapter:

```
public class Typefaces {
    private static final Hashtable<String, Typeface> cache = new Hashtable<String, Typeface>();
    public static Typeface get(Context c, String name) {
    synchronized (cache) {
    if (!cache.containsKey(name)) {
    String path = "fonts/"+name;
    try {
    Typeface t = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(), path);
    cache.put(name, t);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    return cache.get(name);
    }
    }
    }
```

Then in the main Adapter I added two strings:

```
Typeface tf = Typefaces.get(getContext(), "tahoma.ttf");
        holder.txtTitle.setTypeface(tf);
```

That's all! It's working! )) Thank you all for help and answers.

Answer (score -1):

try in xml:

```
android:fontFamily="somefont.ttf"
```

From android 4.1+ the following font are available: http://robotofont.com/

```
android:fontFamily="sans-serif"  
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"        
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"     
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
```

you can also set font programaticly:

```
TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"font/somefont.ttf");
t.setTypeface(font);
```

put the font file in a folder...

Comment: Thank You, but - no, no, it's not working. I already have a file with a font in a folder "assets". But your code - it's for TextView. I need code for ListView. It should use a special adapter, but how "looks" this adapter - I don't know.

Comment: you should create custom adapter

Comment: @user2877972 You don't need a custom adapter just to change the font. Setting `TextView` attributes on list items will be sufficient. (The `TextView`s are inside the `ListView`. You don't set the attributes on the containing `ListView` but the actual `TextView`.)