# How can I change the font of customised Navigation Drawer?

Tags: android

This is the layout of my navigation drawer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- the root view is now a LinearLayout, all other Views are children of this -->
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#121314"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- a separate section to go above the list -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <!-- your image, you can set it later (see NavDrawerFrag) -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/nav_image"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_myplaces"/>

        <!-- a bit of test or a title to go with it
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nav_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Default text"/>-->

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- some divider thing
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:background="#000000"/>-->

    <!-- your ListView is now a child View -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/nav_listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/colors"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want a custom font in the `ListView`, but I've been busting my head for two days straight on this. I just can't seem to get it working.

This is the part where the Navigation Drawer is created:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // need site names for list
    siteNames = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.site_names);
    Log.d(TAG, "number of sites loaded: " + siteNames.length);

    // inflate the parent view (the entire layout)
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
    // now grab the separate child views from inside it
    mDrawerListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.nav_listView);
    mDrawerImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.nav_image);
    //mDrawerText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nav_text);

    // configure the Views
    mDrawerImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.orange);
    mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, siteNames));

    mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);

    // and return the inflated view up the stack
    return view;
}
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15293437/custom-font-for-android-listview and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734273/how-to-set-custom-font-for-android-listview and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576441/custom-font-in-android-listview and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20585744/set-font-for-listview-android, not to mention lots of other resources available online that can be found by searching `ListView custom font` in a major Web search engine.

Comment: Might be, but the problem is how to implement it into my custom scheme.

Comment: What do you mean by your "custom scheme"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `android.R.id.text1` as your textview resource, you should create your own textview xml layout.  You could do something like this

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id= "@+id/listView >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/listItem"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        </TextView

</LinearLayout>
```

The following is the custom adapter you will need so you can set your custom styles to your individual items.

```
public class listAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    String[] siteNames;
    Activity a;

    public listAdapter(Activity a, String[] siteNames) {
        this.a = a;
        this.siteNames = siteNames;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return siteNames.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View vi = convertView;

            vi = a.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listView, null);

            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(a.getAssets(), "fonts/Raleway-Thin.otf");
            TextView tv = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.listItem); 
            tv.setTypeface(tf);
            //whatever other changes you want to make to your list items.

            return vi;

    }


}
```

You then create a new adapter from this "listAdapter" class, or whatever you would like to name it.  Then you can set your listview with this adapter and you should be good to go.

Comment: You cannot set custom fonts via a style resource.

Comment: I did what you suggested, but changed the typeface with java. `Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Raleway-Thin.otf"); TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.listItem); tv.setTypeface(tf);` Now it keeps throwing a `NullPointerException`

Comment: The typeface part should work just fine.  The reason why you are getting null that the view you are accessing is not `R.id.listView`. So it's trying to find `R.id.listItem` inside of the main view, which it isn't inside of the main view.  I realize that this would only work if you were using a custom adapter to set up your navigation drawer. Have you done that before?

Comment: Haha, so it is pretty involved just so you are aware, but if you want control over what each item in your navigation drawer does, you will need a custom adapter for it.  I'll add the class you'll need to my answer so that you can get started on it.  I may be forgetting something in my adapter code, but it should be close enough.

Comment: And this would go in the place of `mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
                R.layout.listitem, R.id.listItem, siteNames));`?

Comment: yes, it would look something like `mDrawerListView.seAdapter(new listAdapter(siteNames);`

Comment: You'll have to pass it the activity as well.  That was something I missed.  In order to access the 'inflater' and 'getAssets()', you have to have the activity to access it from.  Change the constructor in the adapter to include the activity and then pass the activity to the adapter when you build it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56462/discussion-between-user3740505-and-user3331142).